# Connection terminates between Mule 4 and Confluent Cloud with Apache Kafka Connector 4.5.0 but connects with 3.0.7

Tags: apache-kafka, mule, confluent-platform, confluent-cloud

Setting up a (very simple) POC with Mule 4 and Confluent Cloud:
[image]

I have been unable to establish a successful connection using the latest version of the Mule 4 Apache Kafka Connector (4.5.0). If I downgrade it to 3.0.7 and use the same configuration it works fine. Why is this?

The working 3.0.7 configuration (for a basic producer) looks like this:

```
<kafka:kafka-producer-config name="Apache_Kafka_Producer_configuration" doc:name="Apache Kafka Producer configuration" doc:id="2ba6262d-2ff8-4282-910e-5c9e3d347d50" >
    <kafka:basic-kafka-producer-connection bootstrapServers="${kafka.bootstrapserver}" >
        <kafka:additional-properties >
            <kafka:additional-property key="sasl.jaas.config" value="org.apache.kafka.common.security.plain.PlainLoginModule required username='${kafka.key}' password='${kafka.secret}';" />
            <kafka:additional-property key="ssl.endpoint.identification.algorithm" value="https" />
            <kafka:additional-property key="security.protocol" value="SASL_SSL" />
            <kafka:additional-property key="sasl.mechanism" value="PLAIN" />
            <kafka:additional-property key="serviceName" value="kafka" />
        </kafka:additional-properties>
    </kafka:basic-kafka-producer-connection>
</kafka:kafka-producer-config>
```

And the failing 4.5.0 configuration (also for a basic producer) looks like this:

```
<kafka:producer-config name="Apache_Kafka_Producer_configuration" doc:name="Apache Kafka Producer configuration" doc:id="7aa22dcc-7895-4254-ba51-e8bc5e2e9c2e" >
    <kafka:producer-sasl-plain-connection username="${kafka.key}" password="${kafka.secret}" endpointIdentificationAlgorithm="https">
        <kafka:bootstrap-servers >
            <kafka:bootstrap-server value="${kafka.bootstrapserver}" />
        </kafka:bootstrap-servers>
    </kafka:producer-sasl-plain-connection>
</kafka:producer-config>
```

You can see that they both:

- Use an SASL plain text connection
- Have an SSL endpoint identification algorithm of HTTPS
- Specify the same bootstrap server, API key, and secret

There is very little else in the flow other than an `HTTP listener` and a `Set Payload`.

Messages sent using the earlier connector version arrive on the Confluent Cloud topic fine, however using the application fails to start and recursively prints errors such as:

```
org.apache.kafka.common.security.authenticator.SaslClientAuthenticator: [Producer clientId=producer-1] Set SASL client state to RECEIVE_APIVERSIONS_RESPONSE
org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient: [Producer clientId=producer-1] Completed connection to node -1. Fetching API versions.
org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient: [Producer clientId=producer-1] Found least loaded connecting node pkc-4vndj.australia-southeast1.gcp.confluent.cloud:9092 (id: -1 rack: null)
org.mule.runtime.module.extension.internal.runtime.config.LifecycleAwareConfigurationInstance.testConnectivity:179 @23ad5b4f] [processor: ; event: ] org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient: [Consumer clientId=consumer-connectivity-1, groupId=connectivity] Node -1 disconnected.
org.mule.runtime.module.extension.internal.runtime.config.LifecycleAwareConfigurationInstance.testConnectivity:179 @23ad5b4f] [processor: ; event: ] org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient: [Consumer clientId=consumer-connectivity-1, groupId=connectivity] Connection to node -1 (xxxx.australia-southeast1.gcp.confluent.cloud/35.244.90.132:9092) terminated during authentication. This may happen due to any of the following reasons: (1) Authentication failed due to invalid credentials with brokers older than 1.0.0, (2) Firewall blocking Kafka TLS traffic (eg it may only allow HTTPS traffic), (3) Transient network issue.
org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient: [Consumer clientId=consumer-connectivity-1, groupId=connectivity] Bootstrap broker pkc-4vndj.australia-southeast1.gcp.confluent.cloud:9092 (id: -1 rack: null) disconnected
org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.ConsumerNetworkClient: [Consumer clientId=consumer-connectivity-1, groupId=connectivity] Cancelled request with header RequestHeader(apiKey=METADATA, apiVersion=9, clientId=consumer-connectivity-1, correlationId=17) due to node -1 being disconnected
org.apache.kafka.common.network.Selector: [Producer clientId=producer-1] Connection with xxxxx.australia-southeast1.gcp.confluent.cloud/35.244.90.132 disconnected
```

And stacktrace with `End of File Exception`:

```
java.io.EOFException: null
at org.apache.kafka.common.network.NetworkReceive.readFrom(NetworkReceive.java:120) ~[kafka-clients-2.7.0.jar:?]
at org.apache.kafka.common.security.authenticator.SaslClientAuthenticator.receiveResponseOrToken(SaslClientAuthenticator.java:470) ~[kafka-clients-2.7.0.jar:?]
at org.apache.kafka.common.security.authenticator.SaslClientAuthenticator.receiveKafkaResponse(SaslClientAuthenticator.java:560) ~[kafka-clients-2.7.0.jar:?]
at org.apache.kafka.common.security.authenticator.SaslClientAuthenticator.authenticate(SaslClientAuthenticator.java:248) ~[kafka-clients-2.7.0.jar:?]
at org.apache.kafka.common.network.KafkaChannel.prepare(KafkaChannel.java:176) ~[kafka-clients-2.7.0.jar:?]
```

Which (looking at the Apache source code) looks like a zero-byte message response.

Answer (score 0):

Version 4.5.0 may not be constructing and instantiating a proper `org.apache.kafka.common.security.plain.PlainLoginModule` that is required for Confluent Cloud to authenticate requests.